# Swing animation optimization

Tags: java, swing, animation, java-2d

I have been working on a simple animation using a `Timer` on a `JComponent`. However, I experience incredibly choppy motion when I view the animation. What steps should I take to optimize this code?

### `MyAnimationFrame`

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyAnimationFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyAnimationFrame() {
        super("My animation frame!");
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new AnimationComponent(0,0,50,50));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAnimationFrame f = new MyAnimationFrame();
    }
}
```

### `AnimationComponent`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AnimationComponent extends JComponent implements ActionListener {
    private Timer animTimer;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int xVel;
    private int yVel;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int oldX;
    private int oldY;

    public AnimationComponent(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;

        animTimer = new Timer(25, this);
        xVel = 5;
        yVel = 5;

        animTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(x,y,width,height);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        oldX = x;
        oldY = y;

        if(x + width > getParent().getWidth() || x < 0) {
             xVel *= -1;
        }

        if(y + height > getParent().getHeight() || y < 0) {
            yVel *= -1;
        }

        x += xVel;
        y += yVel;

        repaint();
    }
}
```

Not sure if this matters, but I am using OpenJDK version 1.8.0_121.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Calling `super.paintComponent` might be a good start

Comment: After reading a bit about this, I understand that calling `super.paintComponent` should prevent any visual artifacts, but does this effect performance? I might be imagining it but it seems to be running a bit better.

Comment: Since you're not preparing the `Graphics` context for painting, then you'll have issue.  `JComponent` is transparent by default (only realised this after commenting :P), so it has to also update any child components, like the content pane, when ever it's changed, so that could affect performance. You could try using a `JPanel` instead

Comment: I just noticed some really odd behavior when I was messing around with it: it only appears to run smoothly when the JFrame is in focus and my cursor is moving. I have no clue why this would be.

edit: [video](https://vid.me/eqNv)

Comment: It's probably adding additional paint cycles

Comment: Calling `super.paintComponent(Graphics)` has no effect at all since in `JComponent` it just forces update on ui delegate which is null. `JPanel` would work even worse since it does more things (ui delegate is not null in this case). Children are unaffected by what you do on `paintComponent(Graphics)` since it and `paintChildren(Graphics)` are both called in `paint(Graphics)`. The issue is related to the clock Swing uses for painting since your `Timer` is not matched to it.

Comment: @YagoMéndezVidal Since a `JComponent` is transparent by default, each repaint is also painting the parent, so it's a loose/loose situation, either you paint a single opaque component, or you paint all the transparent components up the component hierarchical chain and `JPanel`s UI delegate just fills the background. Swing `Timer` is synced to the Event Dispatching Thread, where repaint events are scheduled. Since Swing uses a passive rendering engine, it has no "timing" or "cycle", it gets repainted ad-hoc as needed

Comment: @willi How attached are you to using Swing this way?  Would you consider trying to use a `BufferedStrategy` instead?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah, you mean painting the ancestors (not children), that's correct. Anyway I'm reluctant to suggest using a `JPanel` because it has more "wiring" behind and I'd better do a `setOpaque(true)` and paint a square behind. About the "clock" I failed batlantly to express myself: I meant it was not in sync with the paintings, not that there was some cycle; but here's what I mean: ideally coordinates should be set on `paintComponent(Graphics)` based on the current instant and not in the times it's been called, because each call to repaint generates a request on the OS to paint that...

Comment: ... that can be served or not but the position is changed anyway.

Comment: @YagoMéndezVidal The problem is, Swing `Timer` generates its events on the EDT, the same thread as painting is done, this prevents thread synchronisation issues, BUT `repaint` is thread safe, as it pushes a new event onto the EDT which triggers the painting process, so in both cases, there are no issues with the approach the OP is trying to use. Because `paintComponent` can be called any time for any reason, you shouldn't modifying the state within it ... sorry, that's how read you comment :P

Comment: Painting is not done in the EDT, the EDT is a feature of Swing but the painting is delegated to the OS through AWT.

Comment: @YagoMéndezVidal `paintComponent` is called by the EDT to perform the updates required, but yes, this is then pushed through to the attached native peer ... I assume after each cycle. The EDT also calls the component's `paint` method in response to changes from the OS, like mouse changes, window size changes etc

Comment: @willi As a suggestion, increase the frame rate (40 to something like 5) and decrease the change delta (to something like `1` or a fraction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a wonderful discussion with Yago it occurred to me that the issue revolves around number of areas, alot comes down to the ability for Java to sync the updates with the OS and the hardware, some things you can control, some you can't.

Inspired by Yago's example and my "memory" of how the Timing Framework works, I tested you code by increasing the framerate (to 5 milliseconds, ~= 200fps) and decreasing the change delta, which gave the same results as using the Timing Framework, but which leaves you with the flexibility of your original design.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new AnimationComponent(0, 0, 50, 50));
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class AnimationComponent extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

        private Timer animTimer;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int xVel;
        private int yVel;
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private int oldX;
        private int oldY;

        public AnimationComponent(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;

            animTimer = new Timer(5, this);
            xVel = 1;
            yVel = 1;

            animTimer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
            );
            g2d.setRenderingHints(hints);
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            oldX = x;
            oldY = y;

            if (x + width > getParent().getWidth() || x < 0) {
                xVel *= -1;
            }

            if (y + height > getParent().getHeight() || y < 0) {
                yVel *= -1;
            }

            x += xVel;
            y += yVel;

            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to slow down the speed more, then decrease the change delta more, this will mean you have to use `double`s instead, which will lead into the `Shape`'s API which supports double values

Which should you use?  That's up to you.  The Timing Framework is really great for linear animations over a period of time, where you know you want to go from one state to another.  It's not so good for things like games, where the state of the object can change from my cycle to another. I'm sure you could do it, but it'd be a lot easier with a simple "main loop" concept - IMHO

Comment: Allow me to add an extra optimization: change the `repaint();` into `repaint(Math.min(x, oldX), Math.min(y, oldY), width + 5, height + 5);` since this animation is predictable we can know more accurately the box to repaint. Also noticed that (like the original code in the question) on resize the ball can get "stuck" outside the bounds if these are shrinked leaving the ball out (maybe it's not relevant for the case of the question, but always a case to have into account).

Comment: I did something similar using Rectangle2D when I was testing

Answer (score 2):

[Timing Framework](https://java.net/projects/timingframework/) offers a way to provide animations highly optimized which may help in this case.

**MyAnimationFrame**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyAnimationFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyAnimationFrame() {
        super("My animation frame!");
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new AnimationComponent(0,0,50,50));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyAnimationFrame f = new MyAnimationFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AnimationComponent**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.jdesktop.core.animation.rendering.*;
import org.jdesktop.core.animation.timing.*;
import org.jdesktop.core.animation.timing.interpolators.*;
import org.jdesktop.swing.animation.rendering.*;
import org.jdesktop.swing.animation.timing.sources.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AnimationComponent extends JRendererPanel {

    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected Animator xAnimator;
    protected Animator yAnimator;

    public AnimationComponent(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        setOpaque(true);

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;

        JRendererFactory.getDefaultRenderer(this,
                new JRendererTarget<GraphicsConfiguration, Graphics2D>() {
            @Override
            public void renderSetup(GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
                // Nothing to do
            }
            @Override
            public void renderUpdate() {
              // Nothing to do
            }
            @Override
            public void render(Graphics2D g, int w, int h) {
                Color c = g.getColor();
                g.setColor(g.getBackground());
                g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
                g.setColor(c);
                g.fillOval(AnimationComponent.this.x, AnimationComponent.this.y,
                        AnimationComponent.this.width, AnimationComponent.this.height);
            }
            @Override
            public void renderShutdown() {
              // Nothing to do
            }
        }, false);

        this.xAnimator = new Animator.Builder(new SwingTimerTimingSource())
                .addTargets(new TimingTargetAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void timingEvent(Animator source, double fraction) {
                        AnimationComponent.this.x = (int) ((getWidth() - AnimationComponent.this.width) * fraction);
                    }})
                .setRepeatCount(Animator.INFINITE)
                .setRepeatBehavior(Animator.RepeatBehavior.REVERSE)
                .setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator.getInstance()).build();

        this.yAnimator = new Animator.Builder(new SwingTimerTimingSource())
                .addTargets(new TimingTargetAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void timingEvent(Animator source, double fraction) {
                        AnimationComponent.this.y = (int) ((getHeight() - AnimationComponent.this.height) * fraction);
                    }})
                .setRepeatCount(Animator.INFINITE)
                .setRepeatBehavior(Animator.RepeatBehavior.REVERSE)
                .setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator.getInstance()).build();

        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            private int oldWidth = 0;
            private int oldHeight = 0;
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
                Component c = event.getComponent();
                int w = c.getWidth();
                int h = c.getHeight();

                if (w != this.oldWidth) {
                    AnimationComponent.this.xAnimator.stop();
                    AnimationComponent.this.xAnimator = new Animator.Builder()
                            .copy(AnimationComponent.this.xAnimator)
                            .setDuration(w * 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // Original speed was 200 px/s
                            .build();
                    AnimationComponent.this.xAnimator.start();
                }
                if (h != this.oldHeight) {
                    AnimationComponent.this.yAnimator.stop();
                    AnimationComponent.this.yAnimator = new Animator.Builder()
                            .copy(AnimationComponent.this.yAnimator)
                            .setDuration(h * 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // Original speed was 200 px/s
                            .build();
                    AnimationComponent.this.yAnimator.start();
                }

                this.oldWidth = w;
                this.oldHeight = h;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I'm getting good results but has one issue: any item you resize, the animation is reset.

Comment: Timing Framework uses a Swing `Timer` at it's heart, which, the last time I checked, was using a 5ms interval as the "heart beat" - Since Swing uses a passive rendering algorithm, it doesn't have a "timing" or "cycle", it occurs when it needs to

Comment: I like the timing framework, I've been using it for years, having tried your example with the timing framework, I get the same issues I do when using the OPs example.  The key difference between your example/Timing Framework, is it's using a delay of `15` ~= 66fps instead of the OPs `40` ~= 25fps, other than that, it's basically the same thing - using a Swing `Timer` to trigger `repaint`s

Comment: You are right, I see it uses `Task` which suggests that it'd do some stuff on extra threads but I don't see it linked to what I proposed. And yes, using a 15 frequency drops the same results for me but... thing is that it solved the issue for me and that's making me question if my second suggestion would work better.

Comment: I like the suggestion of the Timing Framework, don't get me wrong.  Yes, using the `nanos` as factor in the update might help, problem is, I think this is coming down to an OS/hardware issue (and Java of course), but some things are out of our control :P

Comment: For some reason I wasn't familiar with the classes I used in my original answer just to realize I wasn't using the framework correctly (it's years since I last used it). In fact for my proposal I was using the example of how NOT to implement the animation. Feel a bit stupid but the answer is updated. Please, comfirm if it's working or not for you because I have some last shots to try if not.

Comment: It's certainly a nice "cheat" ;) - Still get a "small" amount of ghosting, but it's definitely an improvement

Comment: Just wanted to say, that was an awesome conversation, reminding me of one of the reasons I really liked the Timing Framework and for giving me an idea which can still utilise the OPs original code

Comment: I have to admit I enjoyed it a lot.